# Uploading file to Azure Blob Storage using Streamlit

Tags: python, azure, streamlit

I am currently investigating how to create a web application via streamlit and was wondering if it is possible to have a user upload a file on the front end and have it store to an Azure storage container? I can't seem to find an exact example online that mimics the scenario I'm trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this pretty much possible with az storage ACC
First go to the Azure Portal and create a new Storage Account.

Install the necessary Python libraries, including azure-storage-blob for interacting with Azure Storage and streamlit for building the web application.

```html
pip install azure-storage-blob
pip install streamlit
```

Now Create a Streamlit app in Python, follow the below sample if needed

```html
import streamlit as st
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

# Azure Storage Account details
azure_storage_account_name = "your_storage_account_name"
azure_storage_account_key = "your_storage_account_key"
container_name = "your_container_name"

# Function to upload file to Azure Storage
def upload_to_azure_storage(file):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={azure_storage_account_name};AccountKey={azure_storage_account_key}")
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file.name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(file)

# Streamlit App
st.title("Azure Storage Uploader")

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")

if uploaded_file is not None:
    st.image(uploaded_file)

    # Upload the file to Azure Storage on button click
    if st.button("Upload to Azure Storage"):
        upload_to_azure_storage(uploaded_file)
        st.success("File uploaded to Azure Storage!")
```

And now run it using the below command

```html
streamlit run your_script.py
```

For more info follow azure documentation, I have given the link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Storage%20Blob%20client%20library%20for%20Python